# -o-animation css not working

Tags: html, css, opera, css-animations

I can not get -o-animation to work with Opera. I am using browser version 23.0.1522.77. Additionally, in some versions the animation function will work in Chrome, although not always. 
Do I really need to double my code with -webkit-animation for this to always work?

Here is my CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sAGJj

```
.box{
     width: 100px;  
     height: 100px;
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     border: 2px solid white;
     background: #063c84;
     border-radius: 10px;
     animation: opacity 10s infinite linear,
     colorChange 10s infinite ease-in-out;
     -o-animation: opacity 10s infinite linear,
     colorChange 10s infinite ease-in-out;
    }

  @keyframes opacity{
     0% {opacity: 1}
     50% {opacity: 1}
     75% {opacity: .7}
     100% {opacity: 1}
    }

  @keyframes colorChange 
   {
     0% { background-color: #00a2e8; }
     25% { background-color: #063c84; }
     50% { background-color: #9121cd; }
     75% { background-color: #01b001; }
     100% { background-color: #00a2e8; }
   }
```

Comment: You SHOULD pay a read to this https://dev.opera.com/articles/css3-animations/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to double the code with `-webkit-animation`, because Opera supports `-webkit-animation`.
Simply replace:

```
-o-animation
```

with

```
-webkit-animation
```

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

Comment: this worked. I still had to double my @keyframes code with @-webkit-keyframes for it to work. Is there a better way to not double up the animation code? I would 1 up your answer but I don't have a high enough reputation. Thanks,

Comment: There is no way round the css duplication yet. Beautiful animation by the way. Are you using Sass or LESS? If so, you can create a single function for all your @keyFrame animations and have them exported twice.

Comment: Honestly, I wasn't using either but searching the two helped answer another one of my questions about how to create variables in CSS, like for the time. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the prefix `-o-` Opera ist webkit.

Source Opera — [300 Million Users and Move to WebKit](https://dev.opera.com/blog/300-million-users-and-move-to-webkit/)